# Cython wrapper compile .c files to .pyd using cl.exe (windows)

Tags: python, c, windows, batch-file, cython

directory structure

```
Cextended_API_504/
           lib/
                Cextended.dll
                Cextended.lib
                libcextended.a
           src/
                Cextended.h
                CextendedEx.c
                CextendedEx.h
          example/
                Demo.c
                compileDemo.bat
                compileDemo.sh
CextendedPy.pyx
compile.bat
compile.sh
```

CextendedPy.pyx

```
cdef extern from "Cextended.h":
    ...

cdef extern from "CextendedEx.h":
    ...


cdef class wrapper:
    ...
```

Cextended_API_504/example/compileDemo.sh **[linux]** *(works fine)*

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc ../src/CextendedEx.c -c -fPIC -I. -L../bin 
cp -f CextendedEx.o ../lib/CextendedEx.o

gcc ../lib/CextendedEx.o Demo.c -o Demo -I../src -L../lib -lrt -lcextended -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm
```

Cextended_API_504/example/compileDemo.bat **[windows]** *(works fine)*

```
echo off
CLS
set msvc=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\
call "%msvc%vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe" /c /ICextended_API_504\src\ /ICextended_API_504\src\CextendedEx.c /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib
COPY *.obj "Cextended_API_504\lib"

copy ..\lib\Cextended.dll

rem echo "----------------------- COMPILE STEP  Demo.c"
rem "%msvc%bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c  /I..\src Demo.c  
rem echo "-----------------------   LINK  STEP  Demo.c"
rem LINK  /LIBPATH:..\lib  Cextended.lib  CextendedEx.obj  Demo.obj /OUT:Demo.exe

echo "-----------------------------------   COMPILE & LINK"
echo "-----------------------------------   Demo.c
"%msvc%bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe"  /I..\src  Demo.c  ..\src\CextendedEx.c   /link ..\lib\Cextended.lib  /OUT:Demo.exe
```

compile.sh *(successfully  compiles into CextendedPy.so)* **[linux]**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "compiling"

gcc Cextended_API_504/src/CextendedEx.c -c -fPIC -I. -LCextended_API_504/bin 
cp -f CextendedEx.o Cextended_API_504/lib/CextendedEx.o

#compiling cython to c
cython -a CextendedPy.pyx
#compiling C to .so file
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 Cextended_API_504/lib/CextendedEx.o   CextendedPy.c -o CextendedPy.so -ICextended_API_504/src -LCextended_API_504/lib -lrt -lcextended -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm
```

compile.bat *(error in bellow code)* **[windows]**

```
set msvc=%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\

call "%msvc%vcvarsall.bat" %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

copy"Cextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.dll"


"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe" /c /ICextended_API_504\src\ /ICextended_API_504\src\CextendedEx.c /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib
COPY *.obj "Cextended_API_504\lib"

cython -a CextendedPy.pyx

"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe" /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG  /I. /ICextended_API_504\src\ /IC:\Python27\include  /IC:\Python27\PC /FeCextendedPy.pyd  CextendedPy.c  Cextended_API_504\src\CextendedEx.c    /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib   /dll /libpath:C:\Python27\libs
```

Doesn't through any error, created **CextendedPy.lib** and **CextendedPy.obj** but **CextendedPy.pyd** and **CextendedPy.dll** are not created

I tried setup.py (in windows but didn't work) *(it failed to link functions in c header file)*

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("CextendedPy", ["CextendedPy.pyx"],
        include_dirs = ["Cextended_API_504\\src\\"],
        libraries = ["Cextended_API_504\\lib\\Cextended.lib"],
        library_dirs = ["Cextended_API_504\\lib\\"])
]
setup(
    name = "Probability Cextended",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

in Linux the code works fine only in windows its not working. I know I'm doing some thing wrong in **compile.bat** file but no idea whats wrong in it. If anyone could suggest an equivalent setup.py code (which will work for both linux and windows) that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/c` flag from the second invocation of `cl.exe`.

`/c` means "compile only, do not link", which is why you only get object files.

Comment: Thanks! @Nikita Nemkin but that was not only thing I had to change there where much more and still its not completely functional

Answer (score 0):

I made bellow changes to compile.bat and it worked reason behind was both `.pyd` and `.dll` files were not created together. I had to run the command with `/Fe<module name>.pyd` for `.pyd` file and `/OUT:<module name>.dll` for `.dll`

compile.bat

```
set msvc=%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\

call "%msvc%vcvarsall.bat" %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

copy"Cextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.dll"

"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe" /c /ICextended_API_504\src\ /ICextended_API_504\src\CextendedEx.c /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib
COPY *.obj "Cextended_API_504\lib"

cython -a CextendedPy.pyx

"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe"  /nologo /LD /W4  /ICextended_API_504\src\ /IC:\Python27\include  /IC:\Python27\PC  /IC:\Python27\include  /IC:\Python27\PC /FeCextendedPy.pyd  CextendedPy.c /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib   /dll /libpath:C:\Python27\libs

"%msvc%VC\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\cl.exe" /LD /W4  /ICextended_API_504\src\ /IC:\Python27\include  /IC:\Python27\PC  /IC:\Python27\include  /IC:\Python27\PC   CextendedPy.c /linkCextended_API_504\lib\Cextended.lib   /dll /libpath:C:\Python27\libs  /OUT:CextendedPy.dll
```

After doing above changes still around function has thrown error as bellow

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PrintToMessagesWindow_ns referenced in function __pyx_pf_8CextendedPy_6wrapper_50PrintToMessagesWindows_ns`
and when I commented all of error prone functions it worked fine.

The thing surprised me is similar function to error prone function working, So I checked the header file for declaration and I found the declaration in header file. 
Still no problem in linux only problem's in windows.